# Github push from PHP webserver using shell_exec() backticks

Tags: bash, php, github

I have a Github repository that I use via Atom.io with a client to help keep all the changes for their website synchronized.  The GitHub repo contains a webhook that automatically pushes all our changes up to there live website, but I want to use PHP to push changes done directly on the webserver back up to the repo.  ie: log file backups, image uploads and quick changes that were made direct on the server.

If one of these changes on the sever happens my scripts tell me about it no problem.

```
git status

# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   somefolder/somenewfile.whatever
#
```

If I do this from the command line everything re-syncs perfectly:

```
git add --all
git commit -m "from server"
git push -u origin master
```

But if I try doing that via the PHP shell_exec() backticks `` ` ` `` nothing happens.  I even tried adding pauses.

```
$output = `git add --all`;
echo $output;
sleep(1);

$output = `git commit -m "from server"`;
echo $output;
sleep(3);

$output = `git push -u origin master`;
echo $output;
sleep(3);
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?  Should I be placing these calls in a bash script and then calling it via a PHP template?

Comment: Your first `output` line is missing a closing backtick after the command. Is that a typo when copying here or is it actually missing in your script?

Comment: Is the PHP script's current working directory correct?

Comment: It's also not a great idea to put big / binary files (log files and images) into a git repository on any significant scale... maybe look into Git LFS.

Comment: @Mokubai that was just a typo here, I've updated my example above.

Comment: @Attie the PHP script is working correctly in all other ways, even simple git calls like git status work perfectly. The problem is when it trys to call git commit -m "from server", I simply don't see any output to determine if it's even working at all.

Comment: What about the return code / exit status? (if you can get it...)

Comment: @Attie after the push call is executed I always get this returned, "Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin."  When I do all the steps by hand on the command line everything works perfectly but try doing from the PHP template it never actually gets pushed, even though I get the same response in both cases.